# How to change the path of messages.properties in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

Currently I use messages.properties inside src/main/resources, but I want load messages.properties inside WEB-INF/.

...

I configure in application.properties...

```
spring.messages.basename = /WEB-INF/messages
```

...but did not work.